# Value of property does not match type Number YML

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I am trying to pass a parameter through the `aws cloudformation deploy` command like this:

`aws cloudformation deploy --template-file sam-template.packaged.yaml --parameter-overrides ExcTime=12345`

But it fails deploying because it is complaining that the `ExcTime` parameter is a string and it needs to be a number. Is it the command casting all the parameters as string? And if so, how can I pass a parameter of type number to the YML file through that command?

The yml file:

```yaml
  ApiKey:
      Type: AWS::AppSync::ApiKey
      Properties:
        ApiId: !GetAtt AppSyncApi.ApiId
        Expires: ${ExcTime}
```

Thank You all!

Comment: I've posted an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To refer to your parameter, you should use:

```
Expires: !Ref ExcTime
```

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out why. The `--parameter-overrides Param=value` only accepts strings

--parameter-overrides (list) A list of parameter structures that
specify input parameters for your stack template. If you're updating
a stack and you don't specify a parameter, the command uses the
stack's existing value. For new stacks, you must specify parameters
that don't have a default value. Syntax:
ParameterKey1=ParameterValue1 ParameterKey2=ParameterValue2 ...**(string)**.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy/index.html

To pass a number, You need to specify that the value is a number in the sam template like this:

```yaml
Parameters:
  YourParam:
    Type: Number
    Description: Bla bla bla
```

And then You can use it as a number in the template. For example

```yaml
Expires: !Ref YourParam
```